# How to make a Slug from the Title

Tags: php

I' am creating a slug on the fly. When I review the database my slug row looks like this

```
laal-salaam---2002
```

What actually I don't want is duplicate hyphen between the words.

```
$crawl_slug = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $crawl_name);
$crawl_slug = strtolower($crawl_slug);
```

Thats the PHP code that handles in making the slug from the name on the fly.

The end result should be

```
laal-salaam-2002
```

Is there any other way I can achieve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: You can use another `preg_replace` to change the multiple hyphens to single ones: `$crawlslug = preg_replace( '/[-]+/', '-', $crawlslug );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Simple Function I use for years.

```
      <?php
      function to_slug($string)
      {
      $string = trim($string);
      $string1 = strtolower(trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string)));
  return preg_replace("/\-+/i", "-", $string1);
      }
  $slug = to_slug("laal-salaam---2002");
      echo $slug
      ?>
```